# two nodes on ros android

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Do you know how can I run two nodes en a same activity on android?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208015/two-nodes-on-ros-android/) by [zior89](https://answers.ros.org/users/13176/zior89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run any number of nodes within an activity.
Simply do something like this (assuming your activity is a `RosActivity`):

```
@Override
protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
    NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(getRosHostname());
    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(getMasterUri());

    nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("node_1");
    MyNode myNode1 = new MyNode();     // Something that extends AbstractNodeMain
    nodeMainExecutor.execute(myNode1, nodeConfiguration);

    nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("node_2");
    MyNode myNode2 = new MyNode();
    nodeMainExecutor.execute(myNode2, nodeConfiguration);     // And so on...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0